# WEBSTAGRAM is able to show all instagram user with every detail

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How is WEBSTAGRAM (https://web.stagram.com ) is able to show every user on instagram with every details.Don't they need the user permission to do so.The only case in which it not user photos is if the account is private.Have instagram given their api to use ?

Answer (score 0):

They are scraping the Instagram website for photos of users and hashtags or using the private API of Instagram (which is not allowed).

Comment: Does instagram provides them with thier private api.If not where are they getting it.Also scraping the whole instagram website is very difficult job as they don't even know the username.But when searched on their website they have everyone.The user which is created just know also.